# Ionic serve --lab requiring manually saving app.module.ts before working properly

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic3

We have an ionic project with few pages and a single custom provider. 
The provider is request.ts, shown below. The problem is that every time we launch: ionic serve --lab. The compile would actually fail (error points to headers in the http.post from request.ts), then we have to manually go into the app.module.ts file and save it. Then everything starts working fine.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RequestProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RequestProvider Provider');
  }

  getSomeResponce(callBack) {
    this.http.post(
      "some.domain.net/some/service",
      { "argument1": "1", "argument2": "2"},
      { headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json" } }
    ).toPromise()
    .then(res => callBack(res));
  }
}
```

app.module imports the provider as such:

```
import { RequestProvider } from '../providers/request/request';
```

This is the error we get upon the first launch:

> Typescript Error Argument of type '{ headers: { "Content-Type":
>   string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>   Type '{ "Content-Type": string; }' is not assignable to type
>   'Headers'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   '"Content-Type"' does not exist in type 'Headers'.

Although the problem isn't big, it is an annoyance and I fear it might be indicative of larger problem down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats the right way to use custom http headers

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http'; // import Headers

headers: Headers = new Headers(); // init variable headers

this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // set header

this.http.post(url, data, {headers : this.headers}) // use it in your request
```

Comment: The weird thing is the code works just fine. It fetches a json file from the server, its just the first time after ionic serve --lab it doesn't work. Going in and saving the app.module.ts makes it work. I will try your code once I get back to work and let you know if the error persists.